# Why the Enter key is different in different keyboards?

Tags: java, android, keyboard, hebrew

I'm building an app, designed for Hebrew Speakers, and I wrote this code:

```
EditText E= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    E.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int code, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (keyEvent.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN&&code==keyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "it is working!!!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Well, my device have 4 keyboards, two default keyboards, one in Hebrew and one in English, and two Google keyboards, one in English and one in Hebrew.
Only when I press the Enter kye in the English Google keyboards - the code works.
It does not work for the other keyboards

How can I get the code to work well for other keyboards?
What makes the difference?

**update**

I tried to find out what the numerical value of enter different keyboards, so I wrote this code:

```
            EditText E= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        E.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int code, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+keyEvent.getAction() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

The result is -  only when I hit the Enter Google English keyboard key , there is a reply - and it is "0". And if I hit the "Delete" the reply is "0" and then "1".
No other button is responding, it simply writes in the EditTaxt what it supposed to...

**what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Considered looking at the value of "keyEvent" when you press the enter key of the other keyboards?

Comment: How should I do it?

Comment: Inside "onKey" but before you enter the "if" you log the value of "keyEvent.getAction()" and "code"?